# Question about this RC circuit and voltage across the capacitor

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

I just have a small question about the below problem. How did they get Vc of the capacitor to be 12 V before the switch is opened? Doesn't the resistor use up some of the voltage?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After it's fully charged or discharged (i.e. at DC), a capacitor acts like an open circuit. That means there's no current through R3, which means there's no voltage across R3. That's just Ohm's Law. Since \$V_{R3} = 0\$, \$V_C(0^-) = V = 12 V\$.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to answer your question is to visualize it.

Now we are talking about ideal elements which means that the capacitor has no resistance.
Now I am describing it's working.

1.First positive charge moves the positive side of the battery to resistor and then to the capacitor which has no resistance and thus from the other plate of the resistor positive charges flow to the negative side of the battery.

2.As a result charge gets accumulated in the capacitor this charge in turn creates a current in the opposite direction which is submerged by the current from the battery as the voltage across the battery is large than capacitor at starting instants.

3.As time increases the voltage across the capacitor also increases , this causes the capacitor current to increase, as a result the current through the circuit decreases.

4.At one point when this voltage across the capacitor is equal to the voltage across the battery, no current flows as the current across the capacitor and battery tend to neutralize each other.

So now all these things happen in a time of milliseconds as the velocity of charge movement is high.

So now you visualize that the voltage across capacitor does not depend on the resistance.